# mod rewrite subdirectory as root

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I am needing to rewrite www.domain.com/newsite/ as www.domain.com/, basically I am doing this just in case the new site has some unexpected problem, I can easily roll-back to the original by editing the .htaccess file...

Answer (score 2):

Try this rule:

```
RewriteRule !^newsite/ newsite%{REQUEST_URI}
```

It will rewrite any request that does not start with `/newsite/` to `/newsite/`.